# Add text in file from shell script ( file contains tags )

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code from tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>
    <!--
      NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
      to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
      you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
    -->
    <!--
      NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
      and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
      <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
    -->
    <!--
      <role rolename="tomcat"/>
      <role rolename="role1"/>
      <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
      <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
      <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
    -->
</tomcat-users>
```

I want to add following new role and new user into it from shell script.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="t" password="t" roles="manager-gui”/>
```

How to do this in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know the risk if you try to handle xml/html file with regex.

Here is the dirty and quick way with gnu sed:

```
sed -ir '/<tomcat-users>/s#.*#&\n<role rolename=".../>\n<user....#' tomcat-users.xml
```